# Nested quotes in subshells

Tags: bash, quoting, command-substitution

Say I have to use quotes to encapsulate subshell output like:

```
DATA="$(cat file.hex | xxd -r)"
```

But I need to nest this kind of stuff like:

```
DATA="$(cat file.hex | xxd -r | tr -d \"$(cat trim.txt)\")"
```

I can't use single quotes because those do not expand variables that are inside of them. Escaping quotes doesn't work because they are just treated as passive text.

How do I handle this?

Comment: Why don't you use `DATA="$(cat file.hex | xxd -r | tr -d "$(cat trim.txt)")"`?

Answer (score 33):

You don't need to escape the quotes inside a subshell, since the *current shell* doesn't interpret them (it doesn't interpret anything from `$(` to `)`, actually), and the *subshell* doesn't know about any quotes that are above.

Quoting a subshell at variable assignment is unnecessary too, for more info see `man bash`.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do, but it's usually a best practice.  See https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/Sc2086

Comment: Why is quoting a subshell at variable assignment unnecessary?

Comment: So if I want to have a `)` in the subcommand, should I escape the `)`?

Comment: My `man bash` says "If the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the results." (in EXPANSION > Command Substitution). That seems to imply that we would need to quote subshell invocations.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to escape the nested quotes inside. They get parsed properly, surprisingly!

```
DATA="$(cat file.hex | xxd -r | tr -d "$(cat trim.txt)")"
```

Comment: Indeed, it is very disturbing that it works so simply ! As for literal quotes, the usual rule still applies : triple it, backslash the middle one (`a"b` --> `a"\""b`).

Answer (score 0):

I just had success by treating the `$()` as quoting subshell's stdout, so I only have to use the inner quotes on the variable's expansion:

```
# Part of an MSys2 reimplementation of realpath, hence the `-W`
input="../../My Programs"
output=$(cd "$input"; pwd -W) 
echo "$output"
```

The space in `My Programs` is preserved and no rogue quote marks appear in `output`